# Real valued function concatenation as group operator? For which sets?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, functional-analysis, soft-question

Can we define function concatenation of normal functions $$x\in \mathbb R\\x\to f(x)\in\mathbb R$$ as group operator ?

The *identity element* would be $f(x) = x$, I suppose

Function inverse can be defined as $f^{-1}(x)$ s.t. $f^{-1}(f(x)) = 0$.

In group setting I suppose our group's *inverse element* could simply be this function inverse?

These are the two seemingly uncontested properties which fit well.

---

But... what about associativity? $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$. Are we sure this will be satisfied?

And what about *closure*? What families of functions would guarantee this? One example should be polynomials, but I am quite sure that inverse element would often not exist within polynomials...

Comment: The functions would obviously need to be bijective, but other than that, this should hold.

Comment: Yes it should hold for functions in general, but for which sets? Which sets are able to fulfill both closure and inverse for example? Monomials $m(x)$ will have $m^{-1}(x) = 1/m(x)$ for example, so we will need to expand polynomials at least to rational functions to be sure to contain also inverses, but is this family large enough?

Comment: I don't think polynomials are a good place to look since many are non-invertible (as many are not bijective).

Comment: Well, there's the group of order two consisting of the functions $x \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto 1 - x$. If that's not exciting enough, and if one is allowed to compactify $\mathbb{R}$ into $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, then one can enlarge that example into the real version of the anharmonic group, consisting of six functions $x \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto 1 - x$, $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1 - x}$, $x \mapsto 1 - \frac{1}{x}$, and $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x - 1}$. I'll get me coat ...

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, and not requiring $\infty$, there is the group of all non-constant affine functions, viz. $x \mapsto ax + b$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \ne 0$. And this has another subgroup, infinite this time, consisting of just the functions $x \mapsto ax$, where $a \ne 0$.

Comment: I'm still not sure I've understood the question, because you wrote in a comment $m^{-1}(x) = 1/m(x)$, which seems to suggest that by "concatenation" you mean (pointwise) multiplication, and not function composition. I'm sorry if I'm just being very confused for no reason!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley no I do mean function composition, but for the specific functions **mono**mial (single term out of a **poly**nomial) $m(x)= cx^n$, then functional inverse coincides (almost) with multiplicative inverse $m^{-1}(x)=1/c\cdot x^{-n}$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley yep the affine are interesting, and even cooler are 2D affine transformations, but then we leave $\mathbb R$ for $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: But if $m(x)= cx^n$, then $m^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[n]{\frac{x}{c}}$, and not, as you write, $1/c\cdot x^{-n}$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yep of course you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need closure under composition and inverses as composition of functions is always associative.

---

You may prove this as follows: Let $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$, $h:Z\to W$ be functions with $X,Y,Z,W$ non-empty sets. Then, for any $x\in X$, we have

$$((h\circ g)\circ f)(x)=(h\circ g)(f(x))=h(g(f(x)))=h((g\circ f)(x))=(h\circ(g\circ f))(x)$$

and so $(h\circ g)\circ f$ and $h\circ(g\circ f)$ are pointwise equal and thus equal as functions.

Note that this "proof" is really just analysis the nature of composition as we just shift the brackets around; there is no hidden meaning; composition is inherently associative.

---

An example would the space of all continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which are invertible, or in other words bijective. Composition of continuous functions gives you a continuous function and the composition of two bijective functions is bijective.

---

Another classical example is the *group* of automorphism of an algebraic structure, e.g. for a vector space $V$ the set of all bijective linear maps $\phi: V\to V$.

Comment: This is what I hoped and thought, but I did not remember any proof of associativity so I was not sure.